# How can I have two template classes that are friends with eachother?

Tags: c++

[code of my two template class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOaUl.png)
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmKol.png)

Ive tried using "friend class" declaration instead of "friend".
 [replacing "friend" with "friend class"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x3jL.png)

The errors is caused by creating a Mydeque object within main.

```
template <typename T>
class Mydeque 
{
    private:
        T* data;
        int cap, sz;
        friend class Iterator<T>;

    public:
        Mydeque(): cap(0), sz(0)  //Constructor
        {
            //do nothing
        }

};

template<class T>
class Iterator
{
    public:
        

    private:
        size_t current;
        Mydeque<T>* container;
        friend class Mydeque<T>;
};
```

Comment: The question is WHY would you need them to be friends both ways? I can imagine you want to give the iterator access to the internals of the container... but the other way around?

Comment: Can you add the code and errors as text? See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2752075)

Comment: Idk the homework strictly stated I had to. It said "The Mydeque class is templated by a type T that has a friend Iterator class template" and another part saying "make Mydeque i a friend of Iterator"

Comment: you need to forward declare `Iterator` https://godbolt.org/z/T66feqWEx

Answer (score 1):

You can either **forward declare** the class template and then befriend it or add a separate template clause as shown below:

```
//forward declaration
template<typename T> class Iterator;

template <typename T>
class Mydeque 
{
    private:
        friend class Iterator<T>;

};

template<class T>
class Iterator
{
        friend class Mydeque<T>;
};
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3jMe8a1hv)

##### Method 2

In this case, instead of forward declaring the befriend class template separaterly, we add a separate template clause so that all instantiations of that template are friends.

```
template <typename T>
class Mydeque 
{
   
        template<typename U> friend  class Iterator;

};

template<class T>
class Iterator
{
        friend class Mydeque<T>;
};
```

Comment: I tried that before but it didnt work.

Comment: "template<class T> friend class Iterator;" instead of " friend class Iterator;" was what fixed it for me.

Comment: oh nvm it worked, i just typed it wrong :/ Do you know the difference between what I did and what you did?

Comment: @hobo See method 2 in my updated answer where i've explained what happen in case `"template<class T> friend class Iterator;`